# How to instantiate in tables associated with the record in one of the tables being created first?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two tables where one stores the users and the other the launches given by them in an auction. Below the sending of the code of the tables:

```
 const dadosusers = conecao.define('usuarios', {


nomecompleto: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    
},
nomeusuario: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
senha: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
datanascimento: {
    type: sequelize.DATE
},
rg: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
cpf: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
sexo:{
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
telefone: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
email: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
},
emailrecuperacao: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
estado: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
cep: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
cidade: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
logradouro: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
numerocasa: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER
},
complemento: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
},
statuscadastro: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
}

});





dadosusers.sync({force: 'true'});

module.exports = dadosusers
E a tabela onde ficara os lance é:

const dadoslances = conecao.define("dadoslances", {


lance: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
}, 
 
ofertante: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
},
ncurtidas: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
},
statuslance: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
},
modalrel: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
},
datacriacao: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
}
});

dadosuser.hasMany(dadoslances, {foreignKey: "lanceId"} );

dadoslances.sync({force: 'true'})

module.exports = dadoslances
```

I can create records using simple Model.create such as:

```
usuarios.create({
nomecompleto: "James Silver",
email: "james@gmail.com
})
```

But I can't create a bid asynchronously because the user instance is created first on the site. When trying to create the bid for the user "james" I tried the following:

```
const id = usuarios.findAll({
attributes: ["id"],
where: {
email: "james@gmail.com"
}).then(function(res){
return res
})

dadoslances.create({
lanceId: id,
lance: "$ 500.00"
})
```

But the result of my attempt returns the "lanceId" column as Null. The idea here is that users will first register on the platform and then each user will be able to bid to buy an object and that is why the bid is not instantiated at the same time as the user. My problem is how to create instances in associated tables asynchronously please if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
usuarios.findOne({ // you can use findOne instead of findAll: if email is primary key
    attributes: ["id"],
    where: {
        email: "james@gmail.com"
    }
}).then(function (res) {
    // 'res' is the usuarios record
    dadoslances.create({
        lanceId: res.id,
        lance: "$ 500.00"
    })
    return res
})
```

**Method2**

```
const usuariosList = await usuarios.findAll({ // we need use await to use 'idList'
    attributes: ["id"],
    where: {
        email: "james@gmail.com"
    }
}); //No need ".then( ... )"

if(usuariosList.length > 0) { // findAll return list, so, must use `[0]`
    dadoslances.create({
        lanceId: usuariosList[0].id, 
        lance: "$ 500.00"
    })
}
```